# How to a target all elements 1,2,3,4.........n with CSS selector inside parent div

Tags: html, css

How Select all elements with elements having class `iti-sdc-1`, `iti-sdc-2`, `iti-sdc-3`....n. This class is auto-generated. Please, anyone, help me with this.

I tried to select class `iti-sdc-*`

```css
.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-1 input,
.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-1 input[type=tel], .intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-1 input[type=text]{
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-2 input,
.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-2 input[type=tel], .intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-2 input[type=text]{
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-3 input,
.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-3 input[type=tel], .intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-3 input[type=text]{
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="intl-tel-input allow-dropdown separate-dial-code iti-sdc-1">
<input maxlength="15" class="phone" type="text">
</div>
<div class="intl-tel-input allow-dropdown separate-dial-code iti-sdc-2">
<input maxlength="15" class="phone" type="text">
</div>
<div class="intl-tel-input allow-dropdown separate-dial-code iti-sdc-3">
<input maxlength="15" class="phone" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Here's the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for using attribute selectors, especially the `^=` for the incrementing `iti-sdc`

Comment: How to increment iti-sdc Sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target those elements using this selector:

```
[class*="iti-sdc-"] {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```